# Upgrading from MVC2 to MVC5 project

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-5.1

Could someone please help me how I can upgrade and MVC2 application to MVC5?
Please consider that I had never had any experience with upgrade before.
I do not want to do rewrite only upgrade to MVC5.
I have Visual studio 2010 and Visual studio 2019.
Do I need to install other Visual studio versions?
Can I directly upgrade or I have to go step by step from MVC2 to 3 , 4 and then 5?
I also had an idea to upgrade all the project step by step in visual studio 2019. for example first update everything to .net frame work 4 then 4.5 and then 4.7.2.
I am not sure what extra steps I have to take and consider?

Any idea and help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to be done in phases, migrating from 2 to 3 which require tooling upgrade (already taken care of by you having latest vs 2019). This will require you to upgrade dlls, change the project files. Please go through the release notes to see for any breaking changes etc.. After a thorough understanding, you can get this done.

Ex: Steps to upgrade from MVC 2 to MVC 3 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading

Comment: I am using VS2010 and going through the steps.One of the issues that I have is that in my mvc2 project i have an asset folder and under asset I have my css files, my jquery files and pictures and more even site.css are in there however in the step to step document Steps to upgrade from MVC 2 to MVC 3, it is directing to create Scripts folder and copy all jquery from mv3 in there and have Site.css under content. Would it cause any issue if i don't do that or i have to move my site.css and all my scripts from Asset folder to those folders?

Comment: The best practice is to have the static content like css inside of the content folder and all javascripts inside the scripts folder

Comment: Also, it is better to move these files in latest visual studio which may help in refactoring the paths I guess, but always keep your css and scripts separate. Scripts should be grouped by application features which helps you locate the script based on the feature in the UI that you are binding to

Comment: Thanks I agree with the best practice, it will just take a lot of time to change the paths but my folder structure is not bad either and my current folder structure is also very good it Has Assets and inside it Images, Css and Scripts

Answer (score 0):

I did go through the steps from 2 to 3 using the below blog.

Ex: Steps to upgrade from MVC 2 to MVC 3 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading

However i had an asset folder with all my jquery, images, site,css and... so i did not add the followings and Package folder. ince at this point i just want to have minimal changes to source code.

packages.config, /scripts/*.js and /Content/themes/*.*